# How do I link to specific search result?

Tags: hyperlink

I have a license number and I want to link to the specific results I get when that number is entered into the following form:

http://www.idfpr.com/LicenseLookUp/LicenseLookup.asp

However, the URL for the search results is always the same and not specific to the results (the URL is: http://www.idfpr.com/LicenseLookUp/results.asp).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a sample license number you can share

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/faq/intermediate/faq5.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Use a debugger like firebug in firefox or the Google Chrome debugger. Inspect the form and set the method to 'get' instead of 'post' and click the button.

Now you can get something like this:
http://www.idfpr.com/LicenseLookUp/results.asp?TYPE=NAME&pro_cde=0219&lnme=wew&checkbox=on&finit=A&rowcount=1&submit1.x=42&submit1.y=8